# Perform a git pull without navigating into the repository directory

Tags: git, powershell

I`m writing a Powershell script that (among other things) fetches some data from a Git repository. Normally, I would do something like this:

```sh
# Verify that the repo exists, otherwise create it
if(!(Test-Path $local-repo-path)){
    git clone $repo-url $local-repo-path
}

cd $local-repo-path
git pull
cd "some-inner-directory\..."
# do various tasks here...
cd ..
# Perform other tasks...
```

As you can see, I'm navigating into the folder structure in the repo here in order to perform a set of tasks. It seems to me that it would be a lot cleaner to stay outside of the repo in Powershell, and pass the necessary paths in as parameters when needed. In other words, I'd like to avoid using `cd <somepath>`, and `cd ..`.

I *can* do that for most operations, but not for `git pull`.

**My question: Is there any way to perform a `git pull` from outside of the repository directory?** I.e., something like the following (this is invalid syntax):

```sh
git pull $local-repo-path
```

Comment: why not create an alias for the path, that way it will still remain short?

Comment: check for git qualifier: `--git-dir=` and `--work-tree=`.

Comment: @Serge Thanks, but apparently there is an even easier method, as in the linked-to answer. I'm surprised I didn't find it earlier on my own. **Short answer:** `git -C some/path/ pull`. That will work for pretty much any other git command too - it tells Git where to perform it, which was exactly what I was looking for.